# Angular tutorial error input [ngModel]="selectedHero.name"

Tags: angular

I'm running the Angular tutorial. I'm stuck.

I did a search on here, I found a similar  [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39755336/angular2-cannot-read-property-name-of-undefined) , but it doesn't help me.

The error I'm getting:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 20 in [selectedHero?.name=$event] in ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@15:19 ("
          <div>
            <label>name: </label>
            <input [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="selectedHero?.name" placeholder="name"/>
          </div>
        </div>
"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@15:19
```

I tried with and without the ?. Doesn't make difference. I tried the line:

```
<input [ngModel]="selectedHero?.name" (ngModelChange)="selectedHero.name = $event" />
```

I went back to the page and copied the entire code, it doesn't change anything.

I got the same error on the very first part of the [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2) too.

Comment: You can't use the `?` in two-way binding. Your second example is correct. `(ngModelChange)="selectedHero?.name ? selectedHero.name = $event : null">` is even better. What happens with the second approach?

Comment: I put this in :    <input (ngModelChange)="selectedHero?.name ? selectedHero.name = $event : null"/> , and I get nothing. I just have an edit box, but nothing it is in it.

Comment: You forgot `[(ngModel)]="selectedHero?.name"`

Comment: Actually, I tried that too. Didn't work. Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

Comment: Then you haven't imported the relevant modules

Comment: this is my package.json file. "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line :

From :

```
<input name='name' [ngModel]="selectedHero?.name" (ngModelChange)="selectedHero.name = $event" />
```

To :

```
<input name='name' [ngModel]="selectedHero?.name" (ngModelChange)="selectedHero?.name ? selectedHero.name = $event.target.value : ''" />
```

Comment: I get this error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Comment: please add formModule in app.module.ts

Comment: That was it. I kept trying to add it in, but I didn't notice the modules. It was a completely different file. Everytime I added it to my components file I was getting an error.

Comment: Great you made it ... :)

Comment: For any one else reading this, I had to go back to the code in the tutorial <input [(ngModel)]="selectedHero.name" placeholder="name"/> It wasn't updating otherwise.

Comment: you have to provide the name field also

Comment: @user269964 , will you please also upvote the answer, please?

Comment: this will not works for two way binding [(ngModel)]="prop.val"