# Two way binding, data late?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this:

```
<select  class="readonly"  [disabled]="contractDetails.signedFlag" [(ngModel)]="contractDetails.contract.acontactId">
    <option value="{{contact.id}}"  *ngFor="let contact of contractDetails.contactInfo" [selected]="contractDetails?.contract?.acontactId == contact.id">{{contact.fullName}}</option>
</select>
```

and i have this:

```
this.contractDetails.contract = new Contract();
```

Problem is that i get an error that can not read acontactId of undefined. Any suggestion?

I can not use `[(ngModel)]="contractDetails?.contract?.acontactId"`
because then i get an error `parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39755336/angular2-cannot-read-property-name-of-undefined)

Comment: the accepted answer should solve your issue :)

Comment: again i get undefined for acontactId

Comment: private contractDetails: Contract = new Contract(); and you update your Contract model in your question

Comment: Do you have incoming data... ? Could you please show all relevant code to be able to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to set `contract = new Contract();` in the Model.ts of your contractDetails ... something like:

```js
export class ContactDetail {    
    // ALL YOUR FIELDS    
    public contract :Contract = new Contract();    
}
```

and then also in Contract.ts initialize the fields like:

```js
export class Contract {
    public aIdContact: string ="";
    //other fields
}
```

Hope it helps you...

p.s `elvis operator` (entity?.property) is not suitable for [(ngModel)]