# Angular4: cannot read the property of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to learn angular4 with the tutorial they provided in website

Here is the code

**hero.ts**

```
export  class  Hero{

    constructor(
        public  id: number,public name: string
    ){}
}
```

**in component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import {Hero }  from  './hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {


  title : string;
  hero  : string;
  selectedHero: Hero;

  heroes = [
      new Hero(1, 'Windstorm'),
      new Hero(13, 'Bombasto'),
      new Hero(15, 'Magneta'),
      new Hero(20, 'Tornado')
  ]

  myHero = this.heroes[0];

  constructor(){
    this.title = 'Tour of heros';

  }

  onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero =hero;
  }
}
```

**html**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelect(hero)">
    {{ hero.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
<p>{{selectedHero.name}}</p>
```

when click on each `li` i would like to display details in selected object but i got the following error

`selectedHero.name` is undefined

Comment: Your `selectedHero` is `undefined` initially, thus the error.

Comment: so How do i initiaze? and one more thing what is this `selectedHero: Hero`  declaration means??

Comment: declaration just means, that your variable `selectedHero` is of your `Hero` class. You can use `*ngIf="selectedHero"` like from answer, or use `{{selectedHero?.name}}` or initialize your hero with some default from your array; `ngOnInit() { this.selectedHero = this.heroes[0]}` or initialize your `selectedHero` as a new hero: `selectedHero = new Hero(null, '')` or use one-way-binding together with `ngModelChange`, example of the last option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39755385/7741865

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in the template if selectedHero is set before access any of its property

```
<p *ngIf="selectedHero">{{selectedHero.name}}</p>
```

or create an empty instance in the component (updated answer)

```
selectedHero: Hero = new Hero(12, 'somename');
```

Comment: `selectedHero: Hero = new Hero();` this declaration throws type expected error

Comment: Yes, that is because you have the constructor set up that you need to give the properties some intial value :)

Comment: I have updated my answer providing parameters to the constructor. It wasn't clear that they are 'required fields'.

Comment: @ChristianBenseler well if you look at the class, it has the properties in the constructor, so it's pretty clear ;)

Comment: one more question what is the meaning of this `selectedHero: Hero`  declartion

Comment: It means that the type of selectedHero property is Hero. This is a typescript's feature.