# Angular (2+): HttpClient, subscribe, xhr

Tags: node.js, angular, xmlhttprequest

### Situation:

I'm using Angular CLI. And I'm trying to receive data from the server side (node.js, express). I created new component `card-object`. I copied this code from the example on this page: https://angular.io/guide/http

**app.module.ts**:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatGridListModule, MatCardModule } from '@angular/material';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CardObjectComponent } from './card-object/card-object.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CardObjectComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatCardModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**:

```
<app-card-object></app-card-object>
```

**card-object.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card-object',
  templateUrl: './card-object.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card-object.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class CardObjectComponent implements OnInit {
  results: string[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/?cll=bjc').subscribe(data => {
      this.results = data['results'];
    });
   }
}
```

**card-object.component.html**:

```
<p>{{results[0]}}</p>
<p>some text</p>
```

---

**node.js**:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    var reqCard = {
        results: ['text 1', 'text 2']
    };
    res.json(reqCard);
});
```

### Problem:

I see that json data I receive successfully (I can see them in google DevTool => Network => XHR). But everything that I see in my angular app is *'some text'*. And I see `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` in my DevTool console.

### Question:

Where is a mistake? What have I missed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39755336/angular2-cannot-read-property-name-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your array so that it has a value before the async call completes:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.results = []
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/?cll=bjc').subscribe(data => {
      this.results = data['results'];
    });
   }
```

Bind if results has data:

```
<p>{{results.length > 0 ? results[0]: ''}}</p>
<p>some text</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't have any error messages in DevTool console. But I still can't see _'text 1'_ in my angular app.

Comment: I can't possibly see how your code will work without errors, unless you do what I have suggested above, at a minimum

Comment: show us the content of `results` : `console.log(results)`

Comment: @BougarfaouiElhoucine `results is not defined`

Comment: sorry this : console.log(this.results)

Comment: @BougarfaouiElhoucine console.log in subscribe function gives me nothing;
console.log after subscribe functiongives me empty array

Comment: so your array is empty so there's no data to show in your html

Comment: @BougarfaouiElhoucine I understand that, but I can see received data in DevTools in tab Network: xhr. As I understand the problem is in setting value, but I can't solve it.