# angular TypeError: Cannot read property of 'name' undefined

Tags: angular, typeahead

I am working on a angular 2 release 6 app and on the following line of code :

```
<input #instance="ngbTypeahead" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="item.outputProjection.name" [ngbTypeahead]="search" />
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
DatacartComponent.html:60 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (DatacartComponent.html:60)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:11914)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11307)
at callViewAction (core.js:11548)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:11511)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11308)
at callViewAction (core.js:11548)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:11511)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11308)
at callViewAction (core.js:11548)
```

and I'm not really sure what to do to better check object definitions on the bootstrap typeahead.

Comment: can you post your component.ts code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39755336/angular2-cannot-read-property-name-of-undefined)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please make sure `item.outputProjection` is not `undefined`.

Workaround for you is define `item.outputProjection = {}` in your component `.ts` file.

Comment: thank you, didn't even think of that.  I also had to initialize name as well.

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately I could not add a elvis operator to a ngModel with 2 way binding so I did this and it worked.

```
[(ngModel)]="item && item.outputProjection && item.outputProjection.name"
```

And it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this.

```
<input #instance="ngbTypeahead" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="item.outputProjection?.name" [ngbTypeahead]="search" />
```

**item.outputProjection?.name** will not throw undefined error, it will check for item.outputProjection is defined and if it is so, will fetch name from it.