# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nom_gr' of null ?? on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic2

```html
 <ion-col col-9 class="sildes">
                    <ion-slides slidesPerView="{{nbPerPage}}" spaceBetween="5">
                        <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of lesEboxs; let i = index" (click)="saveCurrentSlide(i)">
                            <button *ngIf="slide.nom_gr != null || slide.nom_gr ==' ' " ion-button block [style.background-color]="(slide === this.slideClicked) ? '#DFF2FF' : '#B8D3DE'" (click)="this.slideClicked = slide"
                                (click)="ecardGroup(slide)" class="currentGroup">
                                <ion-icon class="warning" name="star" *ngIf="slide.nom_gr == 'Pro'"></ion-icon>
                                {{slide.nom_gr}}
                            </button>
                        </ion-slide>
                    </ion-slides>
                </ion-col>
```

with mozilla there is no problem but with chrome it makes me error : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nom_gr' of null

I checked what the webservice returns to me, I have no null in the results so I do not understand where the error came from

can someone please help me please ? thank you

Comment: Probably an asyc issue, where `slide` is null when template is rendered. Try safe navigation operator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39755336/angular2-cannot-read-property-name-of-undefined)

Comment: Use `*ngIf="slide && slide.nom_gr"` instead of `*ngIf="slide.nom_gr != null || slide.nom_gr ==' ' "`

Answer (score 0):

You should use safe navigation `?` operator while dealing with asyn bindings.

So Replace

```
slide.nom_gr
```

with

```
slide?.nom_gr
```

Comment: he tells me again that the nom_gr is null but on mozilla the nom_gr exists