# Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined Angular Observables. firstname is defined

Tags: angular

I'm binding an input tag's value to an ngmodel.

```
<input type="text" id="Fname" value="{{getProfile.firstname}}" placeholder="FirstName" #FirstName/>
```

Here is my typescript component

```
export class EditprofileComponent implements OnInit {

  getProfile: Profile;

  constructor(private profileService: ProfileService)

  ngOnInit() {
    this.profileService.getProfile().subscribe(data =>{
      this.getProfile = data;
      console.log(data);
    })
  }
```

**When I use console.log(data). The console writes out an object of type Profile. So I'm getting the correct data.**

I've done this same exact thing with the ngFor directive. But it's not working for a regular input value.

How do I bind the Profiles first name as the value for the input tag?

Comment: You need to be careful, because `getProfile` will start off undefined. Use `{{getProfile?.firstname}}` instead which will take care of doing null checks for you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39755336/angular2-cannot-read-property-name-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

change the syntax to -

```
value="{{getProfile?.firstname}}"
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's asynchronous, so you need to add ensure that the data is loaded in the template before the component renders. There are a few options to fix this:

**Simple solution**

Add the existential operator/safe navigation operator `?` (to check if your variable exists):

`getProfile?.firstname`

**Or**

Wrap your input in an `ng-container` with `*ngIf`.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="getProfile">
// Add your input here
</ng-container>
```

**Best/Better practice**

Use a resolver to ensure the data is loaded before the component is rendered.

https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/

Comment: What about the [safe-navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths)?

Comment: I know that firstname exists based off the console. This didn't work for me.

Comment: @JD333 Yes, but that `console.log` is printed **after** the template is rendered, hence the error. The profile is being loaded asynchronously.

Comment: @JD333 have you tried: `[value]="getProfile?.firstname"`?

Comment: @jburtondev I did, and thanks for that. But it's kind of irrelevant to the topic.

Comment: @user184994 .. just when you think you understand observables you make a silly mistake and forget everything lol

Comment: @JD333 Have you got it working now? I take it this solution fixed your issue?

Comment: @JD333 OK cool. If an object was being returned (you haven't defined a return type for your function), then the string interpolation for attribute binding would not work. Hence why I asked. Hope you have resolved your issue.

Comment: No not really. I'm still having a problem. I've also rendered this information from a previous component. All I'm doing is subscribing to the current profile. And then displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the async pipe for observables (it will also unsubscribe when component is destroyed so you won't havo to do it manually) it will look like this:

```
getProfile: Observable<Profile>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.getProfile=this.profileService.getProfile();
}
```

html:

```
<input *ngIf="getProfile | async as profile" type="text" id="Fname" value="{{profile.firstname}}" placeholder="FirstName" #FirstName/>
```