# Angular: cannot read property '_id' of undefined

Tags: angular

Could anyone suggest why I'm getting error in Angular 7 while application working

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
```

It does pointing on component:

```
<app-positions-form
  *ngIf="!isNew"
  [categoryId]="category._id">
</app-positions-form>
```

but before that I have:

```
  <div>
    {{category._id}}
  </div>
```

which displaying value correctly.

In my component I have:

```
export class CategoriesFormComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('input') inputRef: ElementRef;
  form: FormGroup;
  image: File;
  imagePreview;
  isNew = true;
  category: Category;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private categoriesService: CategoriesService,
              private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
    });

    this.form.disable();

    this.route.params.pipe(
      switchMap(
        (params: Params) => {
          if(params['id']) {
            this.isNew = false;
            return this.categoriesService.getById(params['id'])
          }

          // of returns Observable from anything
          return of(null)
        }
      )
    ).subscribe(
      category => {
        if(category) {
          this.category = category;

          this.form.patchValue({
            name: category.name
          });

          this.imagePreview = category.imageSrc;
          MaterialService.updateTextInputs()
        }
        this.form.enable();
      },
      error => MaterialService.toast(error.error.message)
    )
  }
...
```

I already tries to set question mark to after variable(i.e. `category?`) that led to component not loaded correctly.

Key point here that my app **is working as expected** however I'm getting this error which quite strange.

Could anyone advise me what is wrong here? Thank you, in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39755336/angular2-cannot-read-property-name-of-undefined)

Comment: reproduce it in stackblitz with sample data

Comment: `<app-positions-form
  *ngIf="!isNew"
  [categoryId]="category?._id">
</app-positions-form>`  try like this..

Comment: @programoholic thanks for suggestion but already tried that leads to page stuck and does not finishing loading. In error console error still same :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Aleksandr Popov  set `isNew` to `false` when you get the category object. currently you are setting this before you get category object. That's why your getting error.

```
 this.route.params.pipe(
      switchMap(
        (params: Params) => {
          if(params['id']) {
            //this.isNew = false;              <-- remove this line here
            return this.categoriesService.getById(params['id'])
          }

          // of returns Observable from anything
          return of(null)
        }
      )
    ).subscribe(
      category => {
        if(category) {
          this.category = category;
          this.isNew = false;    <- set to false here 
          this.form.patchValue({
            name: category.name
          });

          this.imagePreview = category.imageSrc;
          MaterialService.updateTextInputs()
        }
        this.form.enable();
      },
      error => MaterialService.toast(error.error.message)
    )
  }
```

In your child component set a question mark

```
<div>
    {{category?._id}}
  </div>
```

I hope this will solve your issue :)

Comment: thank you! however I still getting same error. Any ideas, why?

Comment: No sorry - that is SOLUTION! Thank you!