# New Reactive forms users. TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm getting

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName'

when I load my Reactive Form.  The form behavior seems to be correct.  My data is being populated in the form, but I still get this error.

I viewed the previous questions about this and the answers don't seem to apply to my particular case.

This is my `UserComponent`:

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  user: User;
  userId: string;
  userChangedSub = new Subscription();
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit started');
    this.userId = this.userService.getUserId();
    this.userChangedSub = this.userService.getUser(this.userId).subscribe(user => {
      console.log('email is: ' + user.email);
      this.user = user;
      console.log(this.user);
    });
    this.form = this.createFormGroup();
  }

  createFormGroup() {
    return new FormGroup({
      first: new FormControl('', {validators: Validators.required}),
      last: new FormControl('', {validators: Validators.required})
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.userChangedSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

This is my form:

```
<section class="user-form">
  <form fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput type="text" *ngIf="user.firstName!==undefined" [value]="user.firstName" formControlName="first">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput type="text" [value]="user.lastName" formControlName="last">
    </mat-form-field>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid"></button>
  </form>
</section>
```

**The Form is showing the correct first and last name of the logged in user, but I am still getting this error.** I checked to see in the form if `user.firstName` is undefined.  I thought this would remove the `TypeError`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39755336/angular2-cannot-read-property-name-of-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the component gets loaded, `user` is `undefined` which is why you are getting the error. You can solve this in a few ways. Either update `user: User;` to something like `user: User = {};` or update your HTML to include these 'null/undefined' checks as follows: `<input matInput type="text" *ngIf="user?.firstName!==undefined" [value]="user?.firstName" formControlName="first">`

Comment: Thank you! I declared: 
user: User = {
    email: '',
    userId: '',
    firstName: '',
    lastName: ''
  };

which removed the error.

Comment: **NOT USE [value]** you're using ReactiveForm, the only thing you need it's formControlName. You can use, when define the form `<form *ngIf="form"...>`

Comment: I don't understand the issue.  I'm initializing user as one with empty string properties.  In ngOnInit I replace this user with one from my firestore.  I'm not understanding @peinearydevelopment

Comment: @CraigTaylor Sorry that comment was in response to anther commentor(but they deleted their comment). I have since deleted it.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment oh ok.  Thanks!

Comment: @Eliseo I believe both approaches work as far as setting the form values.  confirmed in browser that I can do it my way or at the end of ngOnInit call this.form.setValues()

Comment: @CraigTaylor the problem is how you create the form. Why not use `first: new FormControl(user.firstName, {validators: Validators.required})`, to create the form?. It's not logic use [value] and formControlName.