# Angular HttpClient subscribe cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: angular

I have the following component and service:
**Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '{{user.name}}',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  user: User;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    this.userService.get().subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user;
    });
  }

}
```

**Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  get(): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get<User>('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc0af9a310000440a0364b6');
  }
}
```

**User**

```
export class User {
  constructor(
    public name: string
  ) {
  }
}
```

As you can see, I'm just trying to print the user's name. It works, but before it prints the value I receive `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` error several times.
I know the reason — I load the user asynchronously, but how to deal with it?
I found the safe operator:

```
{{user?.name}}
```

And it works. But in my real project this approach will not work everywhere.
I also tried to use ngIf:

```
<div *ngIf="user">
  {{user.name}}
</div>
```

But this will break another part of my app.
Is there a way to render a component *after* an HTTP call, so that I don't have to use Safe Operator or ngIf? If not, then what approach do you use? How do you deal with this problem?

Comment: Put the service subscription inside ngOnInit lifecycle [Reserve the constructor for simple initialization such as wiring constructor parameters to properties. The constructor shouldn't do anything. It certainly shouldn't call a function that makes HTTP requests to a remote server as a real data service would.](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

Comment: Those are 2 common ways to deal with your "issue". I am not understanding why they do not work for you though. Why can't you use the safe navigation operator? Why does `*ngIf="user"` "break" part of your app? Focus on these questions and fix your app instead of trying to find some magic bullet that you think will work because there isn't one.

Comment: As a side note you should not implement any logic in your constructor. Implement the `OnInit` interface instead and make your calls there (like the call to get the user from the service).

Comment: You should call services in `ngOnInit` method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39755336/angular2-cannot-read-property-name-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent it by create default `User` object

```
export class AppComponent {

  user = new User('');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to say that by introducing another extra div in your template will break the CSS, you can use `ng-container` element and have `*ngIf` in that as

```
<ng-container *ngIf="user">{{user}}</ng-container>
```

According to the definition

> The Angular  is a grouping element that doesn't
>   interfere with styles or layout because Angular doesn't put it in the
>   DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct, change your user class to interface:

```
export interface User {
  name: string;
}
```

Or if you want to use the class, change it to:

```
export class User {
  name: string;
}
```

You current code:

```
export class User {
  constructor( public name: string) {
  }
}
```

Means property will be created only when the constructor will be called, and that will only be called when you will try to create the object by using new:

```
user = new User();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need create a DTO for this case:

```
  get(): any{
return this.http.get<User>('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc0af9a310000440a0364b6');
```

}