# Angular API rendering issue

Tags: angular, api

This was answered below:

I've been having trouble rendering the API results from a simple fake JSON. The JSON is at this endpoint: https://testapi.io/api/crimsonsunset/code-challenge-jobs

My `service.ts` looks like this:

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getJobs() {
    return this.http.get('https://testapi.io/api/crimsonsunset/code-challenge-jobs')
  }
}
```

My `home.component.ts` looks like this:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  jobs: Object;

  constructor(private data: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getJobs().subscribe(data => {
      this.jobs = data
      console.log(this.jobs)
    })
  }

}
```

My `home.component.html` looks like this:

```html
<div class="bg">

<h1 class="header">Welcome to your next big role</h1>

<app-search></app-search>

<div style="padding: 20px;">

    <mat-card *ngFor="let job of jobs.data" style="margin-top:10px;">
            <mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-title >The role: {{job.title}}</mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-subtitle>{{job.city}} , {{job.state}}
            </mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-header>

        <mat-card-content>
        <mat-accordion>
            <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true" (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <mat-panel-description>
                    Full Description:
                </mat-panel-description>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <p>Info from JSON</p>
            </mat-expansion-panel>
        </mat-accordion>
        </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
</div>
</div>
```

I feel as though I'm just making a simple syntax error to render the data. It's `console.log`ging everything correctly. It seems as though it's not seeing where `data` is in `jobs.data` on the HTML file.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"seems as though..."*? This is likely a duplicate of e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39755336/angular2-cannot-read-property-name-of-undefined

Comment: What does `console.log(this.jobs)` write on  the console?

Comment: Hi @NicholasK, I get the full JSON back.

{jobs: Array(10), totalCount: 30, count: 30, filter: {…}, languageCounts: {…}, …}
count: 30
filter: {displayLimit: 10, categories: {…}, brands: {…}, experienceLevels: {…}, locations: {…}, …}
jobs: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
languageCounts: {en-us: {…}}
locations: []
meta_data: {ResponseMetadata: {…}}
request_id: false
totalCount: 30
__proto__: Object

Comment: Generally, when describing a problem, you need to be clear on what it is doing that is different from what you expect. I don’t see what the issue is in this question.

Comment: It was answered quite clearly for me @theMayer. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a clear understanding, you can edit your service call in this way,

```
this.data.getJobs().subscribe(response => {
  this.jobs = response['jobs'];
  console.log(response);
})
```

Now in your HTML,

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let job of jobs" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title >The role: {{job['data'].title}}</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>{{job['data'].city}} , {{job['data'].state}}
        </mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>
```

**RECOMMENDED METHOD**

Even the above code fixes your problem, it is not the recommended way of processing the data. The api indeed looks complex. In this case, you may have to modify your data in a straightforward manner.

```
this.data.getJobs().subscribe(response => {
    let job: any = {};
    response['jobs'].forEach(element => {
        let keys:any = Object.keys(element.data);
        keys.forEach(function(key) {
            job[key] = element.data[key];
        });
        this.jobs.push(job);
    });
});
```

**In HTML**,

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let job of jobs.data" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title >The role: {{job.title}}</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>{{job.city}} , {{job.state}}
        </mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: Thank you @AngelaAmarapala. I still get an error that it can't read property 'data' of undefined.

Comment: YES! Thank you @AngelaAmarapala! I definitely wouldn't have figured out that syntax on my own. Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad that helped you!