# When receiving data from service in constructor, received data doesn't get shown in template

Tags: angular

My code goes like this :

```
export class Product  {

product : any;

constructor(private http : HttpService, private productService : ProductService){
    this.productService.onEvent().subscribe(result=>{

        this.product = result;
     })
}
```

and in template, I want simply to display object that I got:

```
<div>
    {{product.name}}
    {{product.price}}
</div>
```

but the problem is, nothing is displayed. I log object that service delivers, and it is a proper object with fields that I am trying to display, but I get this error:

```
core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
at Product_Template (product.component.html:11)
at executeTemplate (core.js:12059)
at refreshView (core.js:11906)
at refreshComponent (core.js:13358)
at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11635)
at refreshView (core.js:11958)
at refreshDynamicEmbeddedViews (core.js:13283)
at refreshView (core.js:11929)
at refreshComponent (core.js:13358)
at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11635)
```

It's really weird and I appreciate any help that I get.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39755336/angular2-cannot-read-property-name-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Getting data from api is a async process.

try this in your html

```
<div *ngIf="product">
    {{product.name}}
    {{product.price}}
</div>
```

or

```
<div>
    {{product?.name}}
    {{product?.price}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly, I already tried that, and when I use first solution that you provided, nothing gets rendered at all, nor it does with second solution. That's what confuses me the most

Comment: add a console log inside your subscribe to check value  of result and this.product

Comment: When I do that, object is logged : 
comments: []
id: 0
name: "asdfasdf"
price: "fdsaas"
properties: "ddsa"
quantity: "asdf"
rating: null

Comment: can you try moving code in ng on init  part ?  just to check if it's works there

Comment: Just did that, and combined with checks in html, but still no result

Comment: if you can add a demo stackblitz then it will be great .. or 
just last thing i can suggest is have a variable xyz = 'someValue' ; in ts and  print it in html ,  and in your subscribe block update the value of xyz = "somethingnew" and check if ui updates .

Comment: I added a button that will log product when clicked, and after initiating product page, when object is logged for the first time, every time i click a button I get undefined as a result.

Comment: Thank you, I will try

Comment: What happens if you use [next, error and complete](https://angular.io/guide/observables#subscribing)?

Comment: If I use next, error and complete, it executes it regularly. The problem is, it seems, that value assignment   this.product = result; is not working. I tried copying result object, but that didn't do anything, since I thought it deletes by reference when exiting subscribe but it is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

try implementing `onInit` lifecycle hook

```
  export class Product implements OnInit {

  product: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpService,
              private productService: ProductService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.productService.onEvent().subscribe(result => {
      this.product = result;
    });
  }
}
```

use check in your html file

```
<div *ngIf="product">
 {{product.name}}
 {{product.price}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I tried that option too and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: add a console and check the value you are getting in this.productService.onEvent().subscribe(result => {
      this.product = result; console.log(this.product)
    });

Answer (score 0):

You might need to run change detection to reflect update in the UI.

```js
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent {
  product: any;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpService,
    private productService: ProductService,
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {
    this.productService.onEvent().subscribe({
      next: result => {
        this.product = result;
        // Make sure you always run change detection in a subscribe block
        this.cd.detectChanges();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this still doesn't work. What happens is that this.product has value that is should have while in subscribe method, but when that method finishes, it reverts back to undefined.

Comment: Put a `console.log(result)` inside `next` block. If the result comes as `undefined`, then you would need to fix `productService`